# Raspbian Python Package installtion errors, Parselmouth

Tags: raspbian, python-3

I am trying to install this package, praat-parselmouth, however the installation does not move forward after getting stuck at either

> "Running setup.py bdist_wheel for praat-parselmouth"

or if trying to install with source code,

> Installing praat-parselmouth.

I have already tried installation with pip, tried updating pip and wheel, also I tried to install it with no cache option but nothing works, the installation is stuck, can anyone help